# Sending emails to external mail server having same mailbox as exchnage

Tags: exchange, email-server, exchange-2013, split-dns

I have an exchange server 2016 with some local mailboxes and also have same mailboxes on Rackspace ( test@example.com on both exchange and rackspace ). Currently the MX record is pointed to rackspace server. I want to send a mail from exchange server to a mailbox test@example.com. The issue is that Exchange is checking mail id internally and delivering internally. But I want this mail to deliver to the Rackspace mailbox by using the MX record .
How can I achieve this, what changes should I made on exchange server?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this configuration? As others have pointed out this simply won't work, but if you share your goals maybe we can help steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, I want to use Exchange and Rackspace together, but from exchange server, anyone should send mail to the mailbox on Rackspace. I know its weird later we have to completely switch to Exchange.

Comment: Right, but what are you trying to accomplish by using those two technologies simultaneously? What functions do you need from both? What is the reasoning for splitting?

Answer (score 1):

You have posted this question twice and the answer is the same in both.

You can't.

Exchange will never use MX records for internal email. If the email address is matched to a mailbox on the server, then it will deliver to that mailbox without any DNS lookups.

You need to review your configuration, which as it stands will not work. The only service that allows you to mix cloud and on premise is Office365.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating my answer from : [your second post](https://serverfault.com/questions/895610/force-exchange-to-use-mx-record-even-for-internal-mailboxes/902013)

You need to set your domain as Internal Relay and then use one of two ways:

1. configure mail forwarding for exchange mailbox to exchange mailcontact on rackspace (you'll need to create custom email address like j.doe_rackspace@domain.com and forward messages there)
2. you disable mailbox in exchange and make user as a mail user with external mail j.doe@domain.com. This way exchange will see that mailbox is not on exchange and will route emails to smarthosts , used in send connectors (only if domain in InternalRelay type)

This is absolutely working solution, but you need to understand what you are doing.